# Q:PaintEvent IOS pixelating arc

Tags: ios, qt, qpainter, paintevent

So I have a `Q::Painter` which draws some circle. On windows it paints the circle perfect but on iOS it comes pixelated:

[image]

and this is non pixelated image:

[image]

I will be very greatfull if someone could help me with this problem. The code is exact the same but iOS renders it bad ...

Here is my code:

```
void CQtPercentCircleWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *pe)
{
    int circleX = parentWidget()->width()/2 - m_iCircleWidth/2;
    int circleY = m_iPenWidth;
    QRectF normalCircle(circleX, circleY, m_iCircleWidth, m_iCircleHeight);
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setRenderHints((QPainter::Antialiasing,QPainter::HighQualityAntialiasing), QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform);
    painter.setPen(m_qpenNormalColor);
    painter.drawEllipse(normalCircle);
    QRectF activeCircle(circleX, circleY, m_iCircleWidth, m_iCircleHeight);
    int startAngle = 90 * 16;
    double dProgress = (double)m_iProgressPercent;
    int currentAngle = (dProgress / 100) * (360 * 16);
    painter.setPen(m_qpenCurrectPenColor);
    painter.drawArc(activeCircle, startAngle, currentAngle);

}
```

Comment: You should provide your code in your question to help others identify the problem.

Comment: I provide it in my question.It is better now i think :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `setRenderHints()` wrong. Change it to:

```
   painter.setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing | QPainter::HighQualityAntialiasing | QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform);
```

Comment: i changed it but it is still the same... pixelated.

Comment: thank you very much, do you know when it will be fixed ?

Comment: Quote: _"will possibly change in 5.4"_.