# No antialiasing with QPainter on iOS. Is it STILL A BUG in Qt?

Tags: c++, ios, widget, qt-creator, qt5.4

I use Qt 5.4 on creator for iOS and android.

I find that all I paint in the widget are "Aliasing" in iOS.....

I found some resources on the web, but I still don't know how to solve this problem.

Does any one have an idea?

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-35271
[Q:PaintEvent IOS pixelating arc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29466993/qpaintevent-ios-pixelating-arc)
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-43476

Comment: Both bug reports say "unresolved".

Comment: Could you give me the report's link?I don't know how to find those report for current bug issue on Qt5.4.

Comment: I mean the two reports you linked in the question. They both say that the bug is unresolved.

Comment: Yep, I know. I just want to know if it is still a bug NOW ?

Comment: Or there are another solution.....?